# How can I write this XAML programmatically?

Tags: c#, xaml, material-design

I am using materialDesign in my current WPF poject.
The code is easy in XAML:

```
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="60" Height="40" Background="#FFB1CB7C" BorderBrush="#FF779151">
    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="TagPlus" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="35" Height="35"/>
</Button>
```

But I have to generate "x" buttons, and I cant figure out how can I do it in C# programmatically.

The Button part is easy:

```
        Button tag = new Button();
        tag.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        tag.Width = 60;
        tag.Height = 40;
        tag.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(177, 203, 124));
        tag.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(119, 145, 81));
        tag.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

But I dont know how to do the MaterialDesign part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MaterialDesign part should be just like the button part.
`PackIcon` is just a class inside whatever namespace is pointed to by `materialDesign`.

As I don't know the exact classes you use, here is what I guess the code could look like:

```
using The.MaterialDesign.Namespace;

...

PackIcon icon = new PackIcon();
icon.Kind = IconType.TagPlus; // Replace IconType by its correct type
icon.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
icon.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
icon.Width = 35;
icon.Height = 35;
```

Comment: There are only 2 namespace I can use:
MaterialDesignColors
MaterialDesignThemes

PackIcon doesnt exist.

Comment: There should be something like this in the top section of the XAML file:  "xmlns:materialDesign="clr-namespace:The.MaterialDesign.Namespace"

Comment: You might even just write the "PackIcon icon = new PackIcon();" line in your Visual Studio, put the cursor on "PackIcon", press Ctrl+. to bring up quick actions and let Visual Studio put the correct using statement into the file for you.

Comment: it was in MaterialDesignThemes, I opened this file of the addon and I found it.